Can I safely add a dimmer to this 15-bulb chandelier?

This chandelier takes 15 candelabra bulbs. Right now they are all incandescent. I am unsure of the wattage of each bulb, but I believe they are all 25W. There are two switches that control this chandelier. One is in a box shared with the switch to the front porch light. The other is shared with another light and a ceiling fan.
I haven't paid much attention to this thing since we moved here, as we do not use it much due to how bright it is. Can I safely purchase something like a Lutron 3-way dimmer switch for 600W (incandescent) to control this? Would only install in one of the two switch boxes.

Three way switches can be confusing on how they are wired.  Suggest you take pictures before undoing any wires(with breaker off) and label the wires, black screw, right brass screw, left brass screw, or something similar.

Two key things to consider:
Three-Way Switches
Two switches that control one light (or other device) are called 3-way switches. They have a number of different possible wiring schemes. You need to make sure the dimmer is compatible with 3-way switches and figure out how to install it properly. Depending on the dimmer and depending on your current 3-way switch wiring, it might be possible to use the dimmer to replace either switch or it may only be possible to replace one or the other.
LEDs
Even though you have incandescent bulbs right now, the replacements will likely be LEDs as they use far less electricity and last much longer. You may even find that once you can dim the lights to a desired level that you want to use this fixture much more than you currently do. So look for a dimmer that is compatible with both incandescent (for now) and LED (for the future) lights.

On top of this: read the instructions for any dimmer you use carefully if you stay with incandescents on this fixture. Some of them require a blank space in the box next to them if you're running them at full capacity.

So to confirm, a 3-way dimmer switch that says it's good for 600W (or 150W LED), is fine for this? My main uncertainty is just purchasing a switch that can handle this. I've never even thought about the total wattage of the bulbs on a circuit before as there's never been more than 2-3 for any dimmers I've installed. Is that all I have to do? Add them all up and ensure they do not exceed the wattage listed on the box for the  dimmer switch?

The capacity (in W for each type of lighting) is item 1. Item 2 is LED compatibility (for future light bulb replacement) and item 3 is 3-way switch compatibility. All 3 are critical here.
